# magento 2 admin url not working and loaded frontend is all messy

Tags: admin, magento2, css, frontend, install

> Admin url is showing 404 error after installing magento 2 on wamp
>           server and frontend design is all messy and css is not linked to it.Error visuals are shown below.

```
Frontend error:
```

[image]

Answer (score 73):

First of all, apply proper permissions, enable apache `rewrite_module` and refresh apache server.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/MAGENTO_2_ROOT_DIRECTORY/

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

For **messy frontend**, run following command from Magento root:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now clear `var` directory except `.htaccess` file and check admin. If you get 404 page, there may be an issue of `Symlink`. Fot this, Edit `apache config` file

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and replace this code :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

**Note:** changed `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`

Now restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` and check admin. This should fix admin 404 issue.

**Also make sure, you don't leave `/app/etc/` directory writeable**

Comment: This worked for me, only I didn't change the permissions to 777 for everything.  Make sure you don't leave /app/etc/ writeable

Comment: @DavidWilkins: Glad that helps, I appreciate your point. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, This worked! I made a mistake first and change the wrong `AllowOverride`. Just make sure its the one under `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: Worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Works Perfect! why its not accepted as answer?

Comment: Minus 1 for the 777

Comment: worked for me after as you said changing the conf.

Comment: You just saved my time

Answer (score 13):

For those who are using **wamp server** on windows **localhost** then,

you can try this:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

in your CLI.

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296641/57334 chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101401/discussion-between-zus-and-kishan-savaliya @MaYaNk

Answer (score 8):

Fixed the same issue faced.

as mentioned above run the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in your Magento 2 installation directory through terminal and give permission.

For admin side this is the error (404) because:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  all
</Directory>`
```

was not present in the end of file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` before `</VirtualHost>`. Also make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enable by entering command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Added that line and restarted apache2. Can now access the admin.
hope it helps.

Comment: How can I do this in live hosting ? I did it in my localhost.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you enabled server rewrites: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION # 1 (IF YOU WANT TO EDIT XML FILE)**

I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2. Go to following paths and delete everything:

```
ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
```

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up `di.xml` in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Now last step, also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

I personally tried it on my localhost using MAMP, EasyPHP DevServer, Xampp and Wampp and successfully installed and using Magento 2.
For further you can check out this link:
[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

**SOLUTION # 2**

Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open RUN dialog and type “cmd” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

> If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer
>   installation

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
>   Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: #1 doesn't work for me, Magento 2.1.0. It seems to work if I add index.php segment to URL

Comment: #2 also not working :(

Comment: @drupality check this article and see if you are missing something else:

http://magenticians.com/fix-broken-magento-2-installation

Comment: read that, still no luck, something is wrong with newest Magento version. Major pain in the ass

Comment: @drupality where you are trying? on localhost?

Comment: yes, vhost conf: http://pastebin.com/452r7fvs

Comment: I've ended using: https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers

Comment: @FayyazKhattak Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296641/57334 chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101401/discussion-between-zus-and-kishan-savaliya

Answer (score 4):

> open the terminal and navigate to magento web root
>
> ```
>  $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
> ```
>
> Step 1.
>
> ```
> $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```
>
> Step 2.
>
> ```
> $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> ```
>
> Step 3.
>
> make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server
>
> ```
> $ sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
> ```
>
> Step 4.
>
> ```
> $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
> ```
>
> Step 5.
>
> ```
>  $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/
> ```
>
> Step 6.
>
> delete cache folder under var/cache

http://gotechnies.com/css-javascript-files-loading-magento-2-installation/

Comment: Always works :)

Answer (score 3):

I installed magento2 (on xampp win7) with composer:

```
1.git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master
2.cd magento2
3.git checkout master
4.composer install
5.php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
6.composer update
```

then i installed magento2 with web installer and got 404 error (page not found) on both front-end back-end pages.
then i opened magento2\app\etc\di.xml
and removed this line

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

also i removed env.php and did web installation once again after that front-end and back-end works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

run

```
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: don't forget permission too. For me, I run after that: chmod -R 777 *

Answer (score 3):

For UBANTU OS magento Frontend to work you just need to go to your magento directory and write this command `sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 3):

**Simplest solution form admin url is**

in core config table change value for 
web/seo/use_rewrites to 0 ( 1 to 0 ) and all cache folder form var

Second neet to disable versioning form admin

#### How to disable static-files versioning:

If you do not want to use static files versioning you can disable this feature in the Magento admin area:

[image: config]

It is possible to change this setting for default scope using the following **MySQL query**:

```
INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
    VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

Then execute next command to clear a configuration cache:

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove all files from pub->static folder and fire upgrade command and deploy command so that once again folder and files will be seen in pub->static folder then open admin panel or front-end. This works for me.
2. If still you don't get then delete all files and folder from var->generation folder and once again fire PHP upgrade and deploy command and check whether admin and front-end is visible properly.

Answer (score 2):

You move to directory install magento2. After, you using command in terminal: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and set permissions for `pub, var` folder have 770 permissions

Answer (score 2):

Just Open the

MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml

and replace below code form line number 574

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>`

TO

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>`

Answer (score 1):

Please check once you enabled server rewrites: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me >

1. In core config table change value for web/seo/use_rewrites to 0 ( 1 to 0 )
2. bin/magento cache:clean config
3. Clearing Cache

Comment: @Teja Bhagwan Kollepara  Thanks for smart and shortest trick to achieve the very complex problem with lot of root causes and aproachces