# Magento2 admin url redirect error

Tags: admin, magento2

I just install Magento2 on my local Mac OSX El Capitan. Apache 2.4.16, PHP Version 5.6.14.

The home page comes up but the admin url shows

```
Not Found
The requested URL /admin_6i2tvi/ was not found on this server.
```

When I add an index.php in I get the following

```
Not Found
The requested URL /admin_6i2tvi/admin/index/index/key/75c3473832b3e20ed68f01102834853b849d9f07a338681d59fdae3925ebd473/ was not found on this server.
```

I can see my .htaccess file and rewrite rules are there.

Comment: What is `frontName` in this ` app/etc/env.php`?

Comment: When I had this issue, it turned out that I didn't have "AllowOverrides All" in my site config.  @Vvvaida links to the question where I found the answer.

Comment: make sure rewrite is enable in Apache

Answer (score 1):

**Source:**

[magento 2 admin url not working and loaded frontend is all messy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy/91142#91142)

I installed magento2 (on xampp win7) with composer:

```
1.git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master
2.cd magento2
3.git checkout master
4.composer install
5.php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
6.composer update
```

then i installed magento2 with web installer and got 404 error (page not found) on both front-end back-end pages.
then i opened magento2\app\etc\di.xml
and removed this line

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

also i removed env.php and did web installation once again after that front-end and back-end works fine :)

Comment: Please copy/ summarize the answer from the linked page you include in your answer. We can't guarantee that the site you link to will always be available so it's recommended to add an excerpt when you reference a link. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for more details.