# Magento 2: Static files are present but shows 404

Tags: magento2, static-content, apache

I installed Magento 2 in my local environment and executed each command:

> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But when I hit the site from browser, it shows following errors:

```
http://127.0.0.1/m2shop.drberg.com/pub/static/version1513076694/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):16 

http://127.0.0.1/m2shop.drberg.com/pub/static/version1513076694/_cache/merged/9de8797d0c615276fc794278a0af8df2.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):21 

http://127.0.0.1/m2shop.drberg.com/pub/static/version1513076694/_cache/merged/c0b5661e7cfc4d3e29c8fc8495e4d56e.js net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):144 

Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):144
(anonymous) @ (index):144
(index):243 

http://127.0.0.1/m2shop.drberg.com/pub/static/version1513076694/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):18 

http://127.0.0.1/m2shop.drberg.com/pub/static/version1513076694/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

All these files are actually present in the directory but Magento is not unable to read those files. why?

Comment: What are you running your local environment with? Apache or NGINX?

Comment: i am running Apache.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server.

If this hasn't worked. Then do following steps:

1. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.
2. Find this code:

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/>
>         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>         AllowOverride None
>         Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

3. Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/>
>         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>         AllowOverride All
>         Require all granted 
> </Directory>
> ```

4. Restart apache2.

Answer (score 11):

I have same issue and its occurs when i am was deleted pub/static folder.

And its Resolved after placing missing .htaccess file in static folder

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# To avoid situation when web server automatically adds extension to path
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>

############################################
## setting MIME types

# JavaScript
AddType application/javascript js jsonp
AddType application/json json

# HTML

AddType text/html html

# CSS
AddType text/css css

# Images and icons
AddType image/x-icon ico
AddType image/gif gif
AddType image/png png
AddType image/jpeg jpg
AddType image/jpeg jpeg

# SVG
AddType image/svg+xml svg

# Fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttf
AddType application/x-font-otf otf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
AddType application/font-woff2 woff2

# Flash
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

# Archives and exports
AddType application/zip gzip
AddType application/x-gzip gz gzip
AddType application/x-bzip2 bz2
AddType text/csv csv
AddType application/xml xml

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$>
        Header append Cache-Control public
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        Header append Cache-Control no-store
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On

    # Data
    <FilesMatch \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/csv "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-bzip2 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # CSS, JavaScript, html
    <FilesMatch \.(css|js|html)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

    # Favicon, images, flash
    <FilesMatch \.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"

    # Fonts
    <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

**Note : -** Manually by clearing the pub/static and var/view_preprocessed directories and subdirectories except for pub/static/.htaccess.

To clear the pub/static directory of all files except .htaccess (which is a hidden file), enter the following command:

```
rm -R pub/static/*
```

Comment: perfect answer! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of look on the server directly, we should check first the Magento setup.

Generally, this errors comes when the setup missing the ***`.htaccess`*** file in the `pub/static` folder.

Follow this https://www.naveenos.com/2021/10/magento-2-static-files-are-present-but-shows-404-error

Answer (score 2):

First please delete 'static' folder before delete please copy .htaccess file in other folder in your pc. After that using cmd/shell run these commands

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

and

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

after runing these. Paste old .htaccess file into new static folder. Thats it.

Your project working now enjoy!