# CSS file not supported Site Broken

Tags: css

I am facing this error message "The CSS Style is not supported because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled ". Done with run upgrade compile and deploy command but still not result

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://13.251.235.211/pub/static/version1591722900/_cache/merged/3d04894622aa9431c93107ff82b415dc.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

[image]

Comment: your `multi-store website` ??? If yes, So you deploy command run particular language ...

Comment: open your css file url, it is probably going to 404. run frontend deployment script otherwise your server is not supporting it. Follow this to fix 404 issue if deployment script not working https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205474/31910

Comment: 4 store views But two are working and two are not

Comment: First check that .htaccess exist in pub/static folder ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is actually in Url Rewrite

> 1st Try
>   First Check that rewrite module is enabled or not in your apache server if not then enable and restart server

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

> if You are Still Facing this Problem

go to `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then

```
service apache2 restart
```

`

> if this doesn't work then most probably

Please Deploy Static Content with language Code Propel Something like that

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB // UK English
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US // US English
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f pt_PT // Portoguese
```

Comment: Already done with this

Comment: are you trying this on local or live ste?

Comment: @HafsaZulfiqar check my Updated Anwer

Answer (score 0):

There can be following reason

1. check if .htaccess exist in pub/static/ folder ? if not copy from magento download
2. check that if rewrite is enabled or not if not than enable it.To check this check if login link works without index.php ?
3. check if pub/static folder is writable ?