# Design issue on live server

Tags: server-setup, transfer

I am beginner in Magento, but I designed a Magento v. 2.3.5 locally under xampp and everything is ok

I transferred it to the server and applied all the modifications in the env.php file and in the  core_config_data table.

When I launch the URL of the site in the browser, the Design CMS of the site disappeared (see photos Local and server) and impossible to access the administration (error 500).

Anyone for a solution? Thank you !

[[image: Local site1]
[image: server site]

Comment: See this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314729/77582

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commands :

set permission first

1. sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Hi Bhanu, Thanks for reply. I already set the permissions to 777 for these folders. but when I type a php bin/magento commands on putty SSH, I get a syntax error like this : <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>/homepages/46/d204221203/htdocs/shop1/bin/magento</b> on line <b>13</b><br />   is it a PHP version conflict ?

Comment: This was a PHP conflict. Now the commands work. But the : php bin/magento setup:di:compile stops at 12%. Any idea ? Thank you