# Al magento 2 pages not found after successful installation

Tags: magento2.3, installation, 404-page

Installed Magento 2.3.0 on locally using Xampp, after installation and setup success, niether homepage nor admin page are found.

Giving 404 error.

I went through enabling rewrite mod in apache conf and also checked user permission, same issue.

What would be the possible cause and how to fix.

Thank you so much

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314729/77582

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `pub/.htaccess` to root folder.