# Magento 2 jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js 404

Tags: magento2, installation

[image]I have fresh installation of magento 2. I am getting below error :

> /pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: share your error screenshot with console log

Comment: how can I share screen shot?

Comment: in your question with console error

Comment: require.js:1895 GET http://m2.gocleaning.nl/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Comment: updated image please check

Comment: this js`jquery-ui-1.9.2.js`available this path ?

Comment: yes this is in the exact path

Comment: check my answer and run below command

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting this error. My problem was solved by running the below command lines :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **root folder** of your *Magento project* and run the following commands :

1. `sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
4. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Magento/backend`
5. `sudo php bin/magento cache:clean`
6. `sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated`

Comment: Not solved the problem it is same as first

Comment: you can try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240635/68695

Comment: I am using nginx server

Comment: i don't know but you can search and try this

Comment: other all files are loading from the same folder so why this file giving error