# Magento 2.0.6 admin not loading in server

Tags: magento2

I have done a fresh installation of magento2.0.6 in server. At Front end the css and js are not loading also, my admin page is showing error. It says the page redirected you too many times

Comment: please check .any htacess redirection rules exit at server

Comment: Also need to run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, you can read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy

-- This might be a help for you

Answer (score 1):

After installation magento 2, If css and js are not loaded then perform following steps.

Open command line and goto magento 2 root folder and run following command :

```
1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex

3. make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enable and then restart the server

4. delete cache folder under var/cache
```

I hope this will help you

Thanks

Comment: My server is not apache..I am using Nginx

Comment: Then you should follow this link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/802

This link might help you. Thanks