# magento2 after installation problem

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento2 in my server, it installed successfully, But after installation facing problem in css and js loading so I tried some command as below :

```
Step 1. $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Step 2. $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Step 3. $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2 
Step 4. $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2 
Step 5. delete cache folder under var/cache
```

After that magento2 frontend and backend showing not found.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Did you deployed styles? `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy#answer-120109