# install Magento 2.1 Error 404 after success installation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Installation from the download Page and the right ownership from [there](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

Ubuntu 16.04

PHP 7.0.8

MySQL 5.7.12

Apache 2.4.18 with configured VirtualHost

And after installation I see the success page.

Then:

admin page: 404

The frontend has some resource 404s:[image]

After a `setup:di:compile` some resource 404s are gone. But admin page are still 404.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you enable [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)?

Comment: check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy/120109#120109

Comment: thanks, it was the static content and the Apache rewrite (fresch Linux (^_^)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Magento application was switched to production mode, that's why static files are not accessible.

There are two solutions:

1. Deploy static files: **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
2. Switch to developer mode: **bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer**

As for 404 for admin panel - make sure you are using correct admin path (can be found in **app/etc/env.php**)