# 404 Error. Magento2 admin page not working

Tags: magento2, admin, 404-page, magento-2.1

**Problem**

Was creating a module. Everything was good, but at some point admin page just stopped working. Can't say on what paticular moment, cause I used `bin/magento` to flush caches, compile and deploy. Now it's loading only main page `localhost/`. No other links. `Error 404`.

**What was done**

1. Checked, if the right admin url in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/app/etc/env.php`.
2. `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Flush cache -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Deploy static content -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Compile -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./`.
3. Copied `.htaccess` to the root from source folder on the site.

**Additional information**

It happens the second time. First time I thought it was one-time mistake. I can't remember, if the symptoms are exactly the same, but they are similar. That time was `Magento 2.0`. Now it is `2.1`.

Comment: check this:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy

Comment: @mayank thank you for the answer. It wasn't workng on itself, but I combined it with another and it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed by combining both advice. Can't say, what exactly helped, but here is the sequence of my actions:

1. `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
2. `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/my/root/folder`
3. `php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module`
4. `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/my/root/folder`

> Styles and js were losted somewhere around this step

4. In `.../apache2/httpd.conf`

set:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
and
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

5. Uncommented (deleted the `#`) in the same file (`.../apache2/httpd.conf`)

   `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`
6. `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Flush cache -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Deploy static content -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./` -> Compile -> `sudo chmod -R 777 ./`.
7. `sudo apachectl restart`
8. At first look everything is ok now.

Answer (score 3):

404 pages on native Magento pages while developing a module are often a consequence of a bug in the said module.

To find out try disabling the module and see if the error goes away:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module
```

To find out what the error is I suggest you switch to developer mode if not already done as it provides way more verbosity in logs and errors:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Now try access the page that triggers the 404 and check `var/log` files content.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was already in devmode. After disabling module the main page lost it's css and js. Admin page still triggers 404. Deploying static content hadn't restored page's js and css. In logs just some old stuff, but noting actual in any of 4 files (`debug`, `exception`, `install`, `system`).