# Fresh install Magento 2.3.3 Admin Panel 404 error

Tags: magento2.3.3, windows, wamp, php-7.1

After install magento 2.3.3 magento admin panel 404 error,

[image]

Website Front-end working good.

Any help thanks

Comment: Enable URL rewrite

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Yes i did https://snipboard.io/TgLOrj.jpg

Comment: can you please try with index.php once ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya What i need to try with index.php?

Comment: try this **localhost/mage2/index.php/admin_1qm73k**

Comment: @KishanSavaliya After using index.php in url https://snipboard.io/eVrsKq.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101401/discussion-between-zus-and-kishan-savaliya).