# Backend not rendered properly after installation of 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, dashboard, opensource

After installation of Magento 2.4.2 both frontend and backend The Admin panel only displays as the attached file. Why is that and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which version did you move from? 2.4.2 makes it mandatory to move the main part of the site into /pub folder. So you will need to make changes to your .conf file to adapt the new folders.

Comment: you want to inspect and see what path for css is being loaded based on that we can narrow down the problem and provide better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Check configuration of your web server and how it matches change in location of index.php. This file has been moved to /pub folder so your nginx or apache configuration needs to be changed to match the new location.

Check release notes for instructions on how to handle this:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html
[image]

Comment: Hey! 
I did an uninstallation and reinstall a new Magento and everything works as expected. I want to close the case but I don't know how, please show med how to close this case, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assuming You installed just apache and mysql.And same issue i have faced.
You can check this link and will solve it.
**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120109/85907**

You need **`AllowOverride All`** in this file **`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`**:-

and replace this code :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands:

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue, I resolved this issue changing base url setting.

**Change Base Url with secure url address like mentioned below.**

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://example.com/"
```