# css is not working in magento 2 cart page

Tags: magento2, css, shopping-cart, static-block, static-content-deploy

I have issue in cart page of my website . Currently home page and product pages are loading correctly but the cart page have issue  Css and js fies in the cart page is not working

[image]

Please help to solve this . I have seen this question [Magento 2 StyleSheet not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49363/magento-2-stylesheet-not-loading)

But  I am not sure i can apply that solution . Please check .

I have tried  `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ,but still the cart page  is same

Comment: Please fix your question and like add a valid screenshot of your working homepage and not working cart page, because right now your question is a mess, you telling us that your homepage is working while your provided a screenshot with broken homepage

Comment: how you understand its screenshot of home page ?  Home page is working fine and issue is with cart page only .

Comment: Please add a screenshot from js console (there should be errors of not loading css files), need to verify if the reason is that the permission are broken or mb somebody rewritten the layout and removed the style files, there are lot of possibilities why this can happen, even exception could trigger it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not deleted htaccss in pub/Static

Comment: Its not deleted . Only cart page have issue . Home page and product pages are working

Comment: Your screenshot is showing homepage I think

Comment: it is a sample screenshot only

Comment: make sure the pages doesn't throw any exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run CLI Commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
```

Comment: hi friend, please tell what will happen if i run this command , i have to run only sudo rm -rf var/* ?

Comment: Rm -rf delete the files and folders recursively

Comment: @Devidas, please do not advice 777! please also add when setup:upgrade, compile require